# Template does not load latest values

Tags: angular

I have list item in my header:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/user-panel" class="nav-link">{{currentUser.username}}</a></li>
```

My component:

```
 currentUser: User;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
    this.userId = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
    this.ApiService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe(data => {this.currentUser = data});
  }

  handleLogout() {
    this.currentUser.username = '';
    this.authenticationService.logout();
  }
```

When a user logs in, `currentUser.username` does not appear in the header, but after refreshing the entire page it appears and works as intended. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have wrapped this template with 'ngIf' to check for 'currentUser' is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ChangeDetection`.

**First**, add `changeDetection` in your `@Component` decorator like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'your-selector',
    templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

**Then**, add `ChangeDetectorRef` as a dependency in the `constructor`.

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) // with your other dependencies
```

**Finally**, after API call and setting data, add:

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

**Application**:

```
this.ApiService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentUser = data;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Also, when the user is not logged in it keeps pinging the api with requests with values of null (well because no username is stored yet as the user hasn't logged in)

Comment: `currentUser?.username` will help you for null handling.

Comment: null handling trick worked, however the outcome is still the same as the original.

Comment: Add my Application section's code to your project and see if the data loads correctly or not.

Comment: data is loaded correctly. After a manual refresh.

Comment: Can you share the component's full code in Pastebin or somewhere else?

Comment: Remove the second `this.cdRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: My mistake, no difference however

Comment: Replace `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and `this.cd.detectChanges();` with `this.cd.markForCheck();`. See, if it works. After changing please logout. Press ctrl+F5, then login.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: I don't know. I'm using `ChangeDetection` for more than one year. And it always works.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproduction of this scenario at StackBlitz?